# Survey on #P and/or counting problems

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, counting-complexity

Can anyone suggest a good and recent survey on counting problems and/or problems that are #P.

Comment: These papers seem to be few and far between. I'd be very interested in a good survey paper on the subject. I noted that Wikipedia doesn't even contain a "List of #P-complete problems".  It's also interesting that there were 3 questions today requesting references for counting problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

L. Fortnow. [Counting complexity](https://lance.fortnow.com/papers/files/counting.pdf). In L. Hemaspaandra and A. Selman, editors, Complexity Theory Retrospective II, pages 81-107. Springer, 1997

This gives more of the structural complexity point of view (complexity classes, oracles, etc.), and discusses other classes related to #P. Although it's from almost 15 years ago, it's really not *that* out of date in terms of results.

Comment: @Tayfun: What is missing? Not that I necessarily disagree with you, I am just curious what specifically you would have like to have seen in addition.

Answer (score 12):

Try [Mark Jerrum's ETH lecture notes](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/applied+probability+and+statistics/book/978-3-7643-6946-0).  A free version is available from his website [here](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~mj/pubs.html).

Comment: I think I found it for free! ;)

Answer (score 9):

Pinyan Lu published a [survey](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2011/093/) via ECCC in mid 2011. It compares three popular counting frameworks:

- Counting Graph Homomorphisms,
- Counting Constraint Satisfaction (#CSP), and
- the Holant framework
- (and restrictions of these frameworks).

He also discusses the current dichotomy theorems and the proof techniques used to obtain them.

---

Xi Chen published a [survey](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=2078162.2078177) as a guest column for SIGACT News in late 2011. It discusses the results and techniques leading up to and including his papers with Jin-Yi Cai and Pinyan Lu on dichotomies for counting graph homomorphisms defined by an undirected target graph with complex weights ([arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4728)) and nonnegatively-weighted #CSPs ([arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.5659)).

At about the same time, Cai and Chen published a dichotomy for complex-weighted #CSPs ([arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2384)), which Cai [discussed](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/01/20/is-it-time-to-declare-victory-in-counting-complexity/) in a guest post on the *Godel's Lost Letter and P=NP* blog.

Comment: Nice! I will read this!

Answer (score 3):

Another framework of counting problems comes from computing the [Tutte polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial) of a graph.  In this framework, any two complex numbers defines a counting problem.

The book [Matroid Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521381657) devotes chapter 6 to [The Tutte Polynomial and Its Applications](http://www.math.lsu.edu/~oxley/bryox.pdf). The previous link is to a scan of that chapter from the [website of James Oxley](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~oxley/), one of the coauthors. Last semester, he taught a course based on that chapter.

Another good reference on this topic is [this survey-like paper](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/MISC/BIBLIOTECA/trunk/Welsh/welsh-tutte-polynomial.pdf) by Welsh.